# Why does Caja file manager can't be executed from terminal?

Tags: filemanager, caja

I can launch nautilus from terminal.

```
wolf@ubuntu:~$ nautilus
wolf@ubuntu:~$ ps aux | grep -i nautilus
wolf      2560  0.1  0.3 1302072 60088 tty1    Sl+  19:21   0:01 nautilus-desktop
wolf      2575  0.4  0.3 1423380 59756 tty1    Sl+  19:21   0:03 nautilus
wolf      5221  0.0  0.0  14428  1052 pts/0    S+   19:32   0:00 grep --color=auto -i nautilus
wolf@ubuntu:~$
```

But, why does Caja file manager can't be executed from terminal?

What is the right command to execute it?

```
wolf@ubuntu:~$ caja
wolf@ubuntu:~$
wolf@ubuntu:~$ ps aux | grep -i caja
wolf      4824  0.0  0.0  14428  1032 pts/0    S+   19:29   0:00 grep --color=auto -i caja
wolf@ubuntu:~$ 
wolf@ubuntu:~$ which caja
/usr/bin/caja
wolf@ubuntu:~$ /usr/bin/caja
wolf@ubuntu:~$ 
wolf@ubuntu:~$ ps aux | grep -i caja
wolf      4852  0.0  0.0  14428  1036 pts/0    S+   19:29   0:00 grep --color=auto -i caja
wolf@ubuntu:~$
```

**Update**

```
wolf@linux:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic
wolf@linux:~$ 

wolf@linux:~$ ps -e | egrep 'Xorg|Wayland'
 1797 tty1     00:07:15 Xorg
wolf@linux:~$
```

Comment: What are your Ubuntu version and current desktop? Which display server do you use (Xorg or Wayland)?

Comment: @N0rbert, Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS & Xorg. Question has been updated with this info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first I can reproduce the issue on clean Ubuntu 18.04 LTS VM.

I'm very dissappointed by the fact that I can't run Caja by any command like:

```
caja --browser
caja --no-desktop
caja --force-desktop
```

and what is interesting is that `caja --check` does not show any errors, also the `~/.xsession-errors` file is empty.

I have remembered that bug was reported previously as https://pad.lv/1846612 .

I do not have time to debug this unpredictable GNOME Shell behaviour.

So I would recommend to ignore GNOME Shell (or even [remove](https://askubuntu.com/a/1266925/66509)) and install Ubuntu MATE instead as simple as:

```
sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop^
```

Or start Caja with something like

```
caja --no-desktop ~
```

Comment: I've installed Ubuntu 20.04 and had the same issue again. Only `caja --no-desktop ~` command works at the moment.