# How to remove GNOME Shell from Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to install other desktop environment from scratch?

Tags: 18.04, gnome, gnome-shell, gnome-panel, productivity

I have just installed the final version of Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS desktop system from *bionic-desktop-amd64.iso*.
And I completely do not like its graphical interface - the GNOME Shell.

So I want to completely remove the GNOME Shell with all its trails from my system without re-installation.
Just want to start from scratch like it was approximately if I have installed Ubuntu from minimal network boot ISO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The single long command for GNOME Shell removal is below

```
sudo apt purge adwaita-icon-theme gedit-common gir1.2-gdm-1.0 \
gir1.2-gnomebluetooth-1.0 gir1.2-gnomedesktop-3.0 gir1.2-goa-1.0 \
gnome-accessibility-themes gnome-bluetooth gnome-calculator gnome-calendar \
gnome-characters gnome-control-center gnome-control-center-data \
gnome-control-center-faces gnome-desktop3-data \
gnome-font-viewer gnome-getting-started-docs gnome-getting-started-docs-ru \
gnome-initial-setup gnome-keyring gnome-keyring-pkcs11 gnome-logs \
gnome-mahjongg gnome-menus gnome-mines gnome-online-accounts \
gnome-power-manager gnome-screenshot gnome-session-bin gnome-session-canberra \
gnome-session-common gnome-settings-daemon \
gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-shell-extension-appindicator \
gnome-shell-extension-ubuntu-dock \
gnome-startup-applications gnome-sudoku gnome-system-monitor gnome-terminal \
gnome-terminal-data gnome-themes-extra gnome-themes-extra-data gnome-todo \
gnome-todo-common gnome-user-docs gnome-user-docs-ru gnome-video-effects \
language-pack-gnome-en language-pack-gnome-en-base language-pack-gnome-ru \
language-pack-gnome-ru-base language-selector-gnome libgail18 libgail18 \
libgail-common libgail-common libgnome-autoar-0-0 libgnome-bluetooth13 \
libgnome-games-support-1-3 libgnome-games-support-common \
libgnomekbd8 libgnomekbd-common libgnome-menu-3-0 libgnome-todo libgoa-1.0-0b \
libgoa-1.0-common libpam-gnome-keyring libsoup-gnome2.4-1 libsoup-gnome2.4-1 \
nautilus-extension-gnome-terminal pinentry-gnome3 \
gnome-settings-daemon-schemas gnome-software-common libappstream-glib8:amd64 libgdm1 ubuntu-sounds

sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

---

Note: if one have previously installed Vanilla GNOME desktop manually by `sudo apt install vanilla-gnome-desktop` and/or Ubuntu GNOME desktop by `sudo apt install ubuntu-gnome-desktop` and/or GNOME FlashBack by `sudo apt install gnome-flashback gnome-panel` and/or full GNOME by `sudo apt install gnome` - one have to execute extra removal commands below:

```
sudo apt purge adwaita-icon-theme geogebra-gnome gir1.2-gtd-1.0 \
gnome-accessibility-profiles gnome-applets-data gnome-audio gnome-backgrounds \
gnome-cards-data gnome-common gnome-desktop-testing gnome-dvb-daemon \
gnome-exe-thumbnailer gnome-extra-icons gnome-flashback-common \
gnome-humility-icon-theme gnome-hwp-support gnome-icon-theme \
gnome-icon-theme-gartoon gnome-icon-theme-gartoon-redux \
gnome-icon-theme-gperfection2 gnome-icon-theme-nuovo gnome-icon-theme-suede \
gnome-icon-theme-yasis gnome-mime-data gnome-nds-thumbnailer \
gnome-packagekit-data gnome-panel-control gnome-panel-data \
gnome-pkg-tools gnome-recipes-data gnome-settings-daemon-dev \
gnome-shell-pomodoro-data gnome-software-common gnome-software-doc \
gnome-theme-gilouche gnome-video-effects-extra gnome-video-effects-frei0r \
guile-gnome2-dev guile-gnome2-glib libgnome-autoar-doc libgnomecanvas2-common \
libgnomecanvas2-doc libgnomecanvasmm-2.6-doc libgnome-todo-dev \
libopenrawgnome7:amd64 libopenrawgnome-dev libreoffice-gnome libxine2-gnome:amd64 \
nautilus-sendto pidgin-gnome-keyring plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-logo \
plymouth-theme-ubuntu-gnome-text ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers \
ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers-trusty ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers-utopic \
ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers-xenial ubuntu-gnome-wallpapers-yakkety

sudo apt autoremove --purge
```

---

Then one can install any desktop environment of interest with commands like:

- Cinnamon - `sudo apt install cinnamon-desktop-environment`
- KDE as in Kubuntu - `sudo apt install kubuntu-desktop^`
- MATE as in Ubuntu MATE - `sudo apt install ubuntu-mate-desktop^`
- Unity - `sudo apt install ubuntu-unity-desktop`
- Xfce as in Xubuntu - `sudo apt install xubuntu-desktop^`

then reboot, select newly installed desktop session and login to it.

Comment: Does this equals to minimal network boot ISO?

Comment: I think, yes. You can run diff for `dpkg -l` yourself to confirm or get list of extra packages to be removed. The GNOME Shell is removed, so objective is really reached. On resulting system one can install any desktop

Comment: Ok noted @N0rbert..