# Forced to use gnome3

Tags: gnome, mate

Let me start by mentioning that I have put some effort and time in looking for answers online before asking here. Since I haven't been able to find an answer I figured I would ask here.

My company has set gnome3 as the default desktop-environment for our ubuntu 18.04 LTS installs.

I've always been a very happy gnome-user until Gnome3. This was never was an issue since I could always just choose mate-desktop which has everything I needed.
In the company install I can install mate-desktop and Gnome3 flashback just fine but can't switch environment at login because of centralized policies.

What I'm missing in Gnome3:

- I want to able to show a bar on the top with the app menu
- I want my running applications the bottom (taskbar) if possible non-grouped

Searching online and trying shell extions like "taskbar" and "dash-to-panel". Using the tweak tool the taskbar extions has the option of enabling a bottom and top bar but it doesn't show anything at the bottom. Lots of posts about switching from top to bottom and 'hiding the bottom panel' but none of them give me what I'm looking for.

My questions:

1. Is it possible to switch to a mate or Gnome3 flashback session without the switch at the login screen? (complication could be that I have limited sudo rights)
2. Is it at all possible to show a bottom bar AND a top bar in Gnome3 and if so how do I achieve this.

Of course if there are other options that will give similar results I would also be much obliged.

With kind regards,

Gev

Comment: Have you asked your employer about this?  My guess is that if your organization's security policy will not allow you to install another DE that is supported in Ubuntu repositories, then they *definitely* won't want you to make changes to the DE in ways that aren't supported by the default system settings options.

Comment: @Nmath I'm not sure if that's really the case. It is however a matter of support on the installed environments. I'm in the process of making the case that I don't mind waving the user-support on that part.

Comment: Simply remove GNOME Shell and install MATE instead - check https://askubuntu.com/q/1266924/66509

Comment: I have considered that but wasn't sure if I'ld run into problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For Question No. 2 it is possible. Have you tried the gnome extension, https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/602/window-list/ which could enable a window list and have a taskbar at the bottom.  This extension is customisable to have your windows ungrouped.